# Typeahead.js not populating the search box

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeahead.js

I was following this [webpage](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-using-node-mysql/) tutorial to populate a input box from the MYSQL database using Typeahead.js

**Server.js**

```
const pool=mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit:10,
    host:'localhost',
    user:'user',
    password:'password',
    database:'table'
})
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("home")
})




router.get('/search',function(req,res){
    pool.query('SELECT tableName from parts where tableName like "%'+req.query.key+'%"',
    function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var data=[];
    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
    data.push(rows[i].tableName);
    }
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    });
```

**home.ejs**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="typehead.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
name: 'typeahead',
remote: 'http://localhost:3000/search?key=%QUERY',
limit: 10
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="typeahead tt-query" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" name="typeahead" type="text" />
```

The typeahead.js library is loaded properly and I do not see any errors in my google chrome console. My database is also connected properly because, I have other routes which accesses the connection pool, which is working properly. The home route is loading the search bar but, when I type a table Name in there which exists in mySQL database, it does not give any auto complete.

Comment: If you look at the network calls through Google Chrome dev console, are you seeing any ajax calls being made with your search terms?

Comment: There are no requests being fired when I type

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/, it looks like you are missing building a Bloodhound object to pass to a Source property of the typeahead.

Their example:

```
var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
  remote: {
    url: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  display: 'value',
  source: bestPictures
});
```

For your script, I would try this change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'typeahead',
  source: new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
    remote: {
      url: '-http://localhost:3000/search?key=%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  }),
  limit: 10
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Using the code above did not work either. I tried to test the basic code which does ot use the remote database and that does not work either. I made a codepen